# How change class css after draggable in droppable

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I have following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dragThis').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var teste = $("#teste").offset();
            var pos = ui.helper.offset();
            $("#posX").val(pos.left - teste.left);
            $("#posY").val(pos.top - teste.top);

            var posX = $("#posX").val();
            var posY = $("#posY").val();
            $('#X').val(posX);
            $('#Y').val(posY);
        },
        containment: "parent",
        cursor: "move",
    });

    $('#dropHere').droppable({
        accept: '.dragThis',
        over: function(){
            $(this).animate({
                'border-width': '5px',
                'border-color': '#0f0'
            }, 200);
            $('.dragThis').draggable('option', 'containment', $(this));
        }
    });
```

In home.php:

```
<div id="mydivcanvas">
    <div class="dragThis displayes">
        content 1
    </div>
    <div class="dragThis displayes">
        content 2
    </div>
    <div class="dragThis displayes">
        content 3
    </div>

    <ul class="dragThis displayes">
        <li>
            <span>
                <img id="imagem_teste" src="../uploads/imagens/.jpg" style="z-index:-1" >
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="dropHere"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="save_voucher" value="Save Voucher" onclick="capture();" />
```

I'm trying to get by clicking Save Voucher only what has been dragged into the `#dropHere` div remain with the class `.displayed` but what is out of `#dropHere` should be changed to class `.displayed` to `.displano`

[image]

after clicking Save Voucher only what has been dragged dropHere should be displayed

Thanks for any help

Comment: Thank you I changed the tag

Comment: Sorry, the question is not so clear. First you give different id for different elements. Appreciate if you can explain you aim once again...

Comment: Do you want a functionality to add a class on the basis of the div, if it is dragged to dragable region else add some other class?

Comment: I put a picture in my question

Comment: Addeing class displano after all content dragged to drophere div followed by button clicked? Is this your question?

Comment: Yes, but only hide what is outside the div id = dropHere

Answer (score 1):

First of all i would say you have an invalid markup as you have assigned same ids to multiple elements. As per standards IDs should have to be uniquely assigned to each element.

So, the solution is to change to class instead like:

```
<div class="dragThis displayes">
    content 1
</div>
```

and change the js:

```
$('.dragThis').draggable({
    // other code as is
});
```

You need to use `drop:fn` callback:

```
$('#dropHere').droppable({
    accept: '.dragThis', // <----change to class selector
    over: function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'border-width': '5px',
            'border-color': '#0f0'
        }, 200);
        $('.dragThis').draggable('option', 'containment', $(this));
    },
    drop:function(event, ui){
       $(ui.draggable).toggleClass('displayes displano'); //<---change the css class here.
       $(ui.draggable).siblings('.dragThis').hide(); // hide others as they are siblings
    }
});
```

Check a demo here:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
#draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
.active{background:red !important; color:white !important;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
 
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Jai, I put a picture in my question

Comment: @Zeli you can add this `$(ui.draggable).parent().hide();`.

Comment: Where should I add? In drop:function(event, ui){ $(ui.draggable).parent("mydivcanvas").hide("dragthis");}  ?

Comment: Ah!! Missed to mention. Right there.

Comment: @zeli actually the PIC confused me as you wrapped them in a box. I thought they were in some wrapper div so I mentioned to use parent() method but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Put any random class name to the content divs which is being dragged and are inside drophere div by writeing code inside drop event function, so that those divs which are inside drophere div can easily selected on the basis of that class and finally on the button click find those all content div on the page without those class and once you have those divs you can remove and add classes easily.